# Do Xamarin supports NetTcpBinding WCF?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

I am creating a professional software and I would like to know if NetTcpBinding is available with Xamarin

Today, I have a full working WCF TCP service but I doesn't found informations about TCP support
Now, I am creating an Android version of my Winforms app

Shall I use HTTP or TCP binding ?

Thank you for you help

Comment: I think it is better to stick with HTTP.....Moreover If you have WCF service then you may wanna think about converting it to Rest service so that it is compatible with your mobile app....

Answer (score 1):

since the netTcp binding not supported yet ,you should use http

see the below link :
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1677/nettcp

Answer (score 0):

NetTcp does not route over internet. So this is not the correct binding for mobiles app which must route over internet.